# Ignore Inactive List Members option in marketing List Creation?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

When i create the new marketing list I find the "**Ignore Inactive List Members options**".
What the use of of that?i Searched a lot but i Don't get the  knowledge .what is the use of it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If set to "Yes" inactive records in the marketing list will not be included in marketing activities related to the marketing list (eg, campaigns, quick campaigns).
The records will show in the marketing list, but will not be assigned activities from campaigns.
See this blog [usingmscrm](http://usingmscrm.blogspot.com/2010/01/microsoft-dynamic-crm-40-marketing-list.html) .